# Django makemigrations and migrate unbearably slow / freeze

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using Django 1.8.6 for a small project. It has about 5 small models. When I run `makemigrations` and `migrate` locally on my Mac, it takes about 3-4 seconds to finish and apply migrations to the SQLite DB. However, when I try doing the same thing on the production server, each of the commands freezes.

Here is the point at which it freezes:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, sekizai, sortedm2m, mptt, absolute, aldryn_reversion, aldryn_common, messages, treebeard, emailit, aldryn_apphooks_config, aldryn_translation_tools, parler, aldryn_boilerplates, djangocms_admin_style
  Apply all migrations: djangocms_video, page_extensions, aldryn_forms, filer, email_notifications, aldryn_newsblog, djangocms_picture, aldryn_people, menus, djangocms_text_ckeditor, djangocms_link, sessions, djangocms_column, djangocms_googlemap, auth, djangocms_snippet, captcha, aldryn_bootstrap3, easy_thumbnails, admin, djangocms_file, cms, taggit, reversion, contenttypes, sites, social_icon, aldryn_categories, djangocms_style
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states...
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? If it helps, I am using an EC2 AWS instance with CentOS as the production server.

Comment: Why dont you use Postgre SQL or MySQL as DB backend if your db contents are large? SQLite is suitable for light weight applications.

Comment: My application is very light. As i said, there are only 3-4 models that i wrote and DB size is about 1.5Mb.